# Print Fieldset Expanded Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-foundation

My HTML is :

`<input type="button" value="Print" id="btnPrint">
<fieldset id="FieldsetLegal" class="collapsible collapsed">
       <legend id="legleg">Legal
        </legend>
</fieldset>`

JS :

```
    $('#btnPrint').click(function()
{

    $("#FieldsetLegal").collapsible({
        toggle: true
    });

    window.print();
});
```

I want before print the page i expand the fieldset to print it's content.
How i can print only some contents not all the page (If it's possible).